# DC over current protection idea needed for step down converter input

Tags: protection, surge-protection, over-current

I ride an electric motorcycle which is powered by a 26s 96V Li-ion battery. It has regen braking that charge the battery with 50A current. All the lights are powered by a 60v-120v to 12V 15A DC step down converter. The converter draws power directly from the battery. The battery charging and discharging wires are the same.

When I engage braking while the battery is full, regen braking charge the battery for a second. Then the battery BMS naturally stops the charging because battery is full. I believe at that moment my step down converter gets pumped with the 50A for a very very short time before the motor controller quits regenerative braking. The step down converter dies in about 2 weeks because this is repeating everyday when I start the journey and brake the first time. I've had to replace 4 converters within 2 months.

Is there a way to limit the current that can pass through to the converter. Ideally a 100V 2A limit?

Or is it better to add high wattage resistors to all the lights and give power directly from the 96V battery? I think this method would waste a lot of power.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: the converter will only draw the current it requires. Just because the batteries are being charged at 50A, that 50A doesn't necessarily flow through your converter. you need to determine why your converters are failing - they could just be crappy converters. Your suggestion of using resistors to drop the voltage would work, but is not a good idea for the reasons you suggest. Simple solution is to get a decent converter.

Comment: Is it not possible that the 50A surge would over power into the converter? Isn't that the same reason we have surge protection in the households? Because this 50A is created by a generator. Not by a battery. It only gets into the converters exactly when the battery stops collecting it and there is a milliseconds delay in the controller to stop generating the 50A current.

Comment: there is a possibility of over voltage. Over current ( unless caused by over-voltage) is less likely. To charge a battery, you need to apply a higher voltage than the battery itself. The higher the voltage, the higher the current. Whether the voltage would exceed 120VDC, I don't know. Hopefully someone with some specific experience in charging Li Ion batteries can chime in.  A 'surge' is a high voltage event - a surge protector attempts to limit the voltage by drawing more current and hopefully trips the breaker if it gets too high.

Comment: Study the difference between voltage and current and things will become clearer for you.  You seem to misunderstand what current is.

Comment: Question clear enough.

Comment: Can people who found this question unclear please explain why.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted in comments - over voltage from the charging surge is very probably the issue.

A solution is a small resistance series resistor to the converter and a suitably robust zener on the converter side at a voltage such that it conducts only above usual charge voltage. There are other devices that achieve this directly but repeat energy surges tend to reduce their lifetimes.
This needs suitably power rated R and zener.

A lower power dissipation solution is an eg MOSFET switch between charge circuit and converter that opens when charge voltage exceeds converter Vinmax. This will extinguish your lights briefly. A small battery on the converter output that supplies voltage only when the converter doesn't
provide voltage will prevent this.
A battery with VBat > Vconverter_out and a diode from the battery will achieve this.

Comment: I have now made 2 battery packs of 12v 15ah each. Using them instead of converters. I made 2 because of all the times I had to ride the bike home without lights. 1 battery primary and 1 as backup. I switch the usage between them weekly by a 30A DPDT switch. So my problems are gone for now :)

Comment: But to answer your questions about the values, the DC-DC converters were 120v to 12v 15A. The controller's capacitors are 160V and the MOSFETS are 135V. And battery ofcourse 109.2V at full charge.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Russell, the problem seems to be over-voltage, not overcurrent. Basically the regen braking controller tries to dump power into the battery, but the BMS opens its switch, so voltage rises until something breaks.

However the regen braking controller doesn't break, so it must limit voltage at a value that is safe for it, but not safe for the 12V DC-DC converter.

So, first things first, you must know what the maximum voltage is, if you want to use a 12V DC-DC converter that will withstand it without breaking.

One simple way would be to look at the motor controller and check the voltage rating of the larger power supply capacitors on the board. That will give you an idea. If it has a manual or datasheet, you could also use that.

You could also measure it, but you'll have to tell us what kind of equipment you have. Do you have a multimeter with a peak function? It would probably not be a good idea to duct tape an oscilloscope to the handlebars and test while braking, unless you happen to have a portable scope...

Basically you need to know what the peak voltage is. Then you can select a 12V DC-DC converter that will work with that, or modify the one you have.

I wouldn't recommend an automatic overvoltage protection switch, because that would turn the lights off when braking, which is not exactly safe.

Answer (score 0):

A stepdown  switching supply has a control element,
a pass transistor, and an inductor.   If the
control element (usually a PWM integrated circuit) can
take the input voltage, and the pass transistor can
shut OFF its input voltage, there should be no problem.

A regenerative braking event that suddenly loses
its battery connection is likely to feel very
odd to the rider; his brakes just stop working!
So, I suspect that the battery management system does
NOT simply disconnect the battery, but shunts some
braking current into another (resistor?) path.

That other current path is presumably not
connected to the battery, so current there should
not hurt the regulator.   An analysis of the failed
regulator should be performed, before assuming
this is a brake-related issue.

Break-generated  power is unlikely to over-charge a battery,
because it delivers kinetic energy that, presumably,
came from the battery in preceding minutes.
One does not expect a battery to be over-charged by
returning part of its initial stored energy.

Comment: The question is about the regulator burning. Battery is never overcharged. However, to answer your question, yes my controller does release regent instantly and the vehicle lose regent braking power right away. Have to be ready with the hydraulic levers and pads :D. As someone else suggested the the c controller maybe charging the battery at a higher voltage than the normal battery charger would. Because my at home AC-DC battery charger is within the operating voltage of the 12v regulator, I assumed the controller regen charge is too. But the controller maybe charging battery at higher volts

Comment: @Roguenite If the headlights are powered from the battery, and the regen braking stops charging the battery, that should make battery voltage DROP slightly, not rise.   It should be a non-event to a battery-powered regulator, not an overstress leading to burnout.   The scenario of regen braking just cutting out seems like a bad design decision to me.